# How to access a URL through jQuery $.get() method on a ASP.NET WebForm?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using ASP.NET WebForms and one of the asp pages serves a pdf file through its Page_Load event. Locally I can access it through a URL like:

```
http://localhost:2091/Pages/Search/ViewPdf.aspx?id=1
```

And it works perfectly. The problem is when I try to access it using Ajax. When I run the $.get() method of jQuery:

```
$.get({
    url: "http://localhost:2091/Pages/Search/ViewPdf.aspx?id=1",
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I get the 404 Not Found error and in the console, the $.get() method is trying to access this URL:

```
http://localhost:2091/Paginas/Search/[object%20Object]
```

If try to access the URL directly on the browser or by using cURL everything works fine, but through the $.get() calling it doesn't. Why? What can I do?

Comment: I think theres a version of $.get where the url and the values are separated, you could try using that one?

Comment: Have you tried setting dataType to html?

Comment: Have you tried $.ajax and specifying the datatype as pdf and using id as a data parameter?

Comment: Thank you all. The problem was solved by passing the values separated and setting the dataType to application/pdf as you all suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the URL parameters.  Also ensure that you're sending using the same domain to avoid making a cross origin request.

```
$.get( "http://localhost:2091/Pages/Search/ViewPdf.aspx", { id: 1 } )
 .done(function( data ) {
     alert( "Data Loaded...do stuff here" );
 });
```

In addition, it looks like the server received the original request and subsequently redirected to `http://localhost:2091/Paginas/Search/[object%20Object]` so take a look at your server-side logic to see why it's redirecting to an invalid URL